# saveDelimitedColumns

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, stored-procedures, ssms

I am using the stored procedure, saveDelimitedColumns (found: http://www.virtualobjectives.com.au/sqlserver/saving_), to save data results as a .csv file. This works great with one exception...when it saves as a .csv file the column headers within excel have brackets. For example, [Client ID], I would like the column heading to be without brackets, as Client ID.

Below is the savedelimitedcolumns stored procedure and I cannot figure out if there is a way to make it so there are no brackets when it publishes as a .csv file.

Is it possible to make an alteration somewhere in the code below to accomplish this?

Thank you,

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SaveDelimitedColumns]
@PCWrite varchar(1000) = NULL,
@DBFetch varchar(4000),
@DBWhere varchar(2000) = NULL,
@DBThere varchar(2000) = NULL,
@DBUltra bit = 1,
@Delimiter varchar(100) = 'CHAR(44)', -- Default is ,
@TextQuote varchar(100) = 'CHAR(34)', -- Default is "  Use SPACE(0) for none.
@Header bit = 0, -- Output header. Default is 0.
@NullQuoted bit = 0,
@DateTimeStyle tinyint = 120 -- CONVERT Date Time Style. Default is ODBC canonical yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss(24h)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Return int
DECLARE @Retain int
DECLARE @Status int

SET @Status = 0

DECLARE @TPre varchar(10)

DECLARE @TDo3 tinyint
DECLARE @TDo4 tinyint

SET @TPre = ''

SET @TDo3 = LEN(@TPre)
SET @TDo4 = LEN(@TPre) + 1

DECLARE @DBAE varchar(40)
DECLARE @Task varchar(6000)
DECLARE @Bank varchar(4000)
DECLARE @Cash varchar(2000)
DECLARE @Risk varchar(2000)
DECLARE @Next varchar(8000)
DECLARE @Save varchar(8000)
DECLARE @Work varchar(8000)
DECLARE @Wish varchar(max)

DECLARE @Name varchar(100)
DECLARE @Same varchar(100)

DECLARE @Rank smallint
DECLARE @Kind varchar(20)
DECLARE @Mask bit
DECLARE @Bond bit
DECLARE @Size int
DECLARE @Wide smallint
DECLARE @More smallint

DECLARE @DBAI varchar(2000)
DECLARE @DBAO varchar(8000)
DECLARE @DBAU varchar(max)

DECLARE @Fuse int
DECLARE @File int

DECLARE @HeaderString varchar(8000)
DECLARE @HeaderDone int

SET @DBAE = '##SaveFile' + RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(10),@@SPID+100000),5)

SET @Task = 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects WHERE name = ' + CHAR(39) + @DBAE + CHAR(39) + ') DROP TABLE ' + @DBAE
EXECUTE (@Task)

SET @Bank = @TPre + @DBFetch

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE RTRIM(type) = 'U' AND name = @Bank)
BEGIN
    SET @Bank = CASE WHEN LEFT(LTRIM(@DBFetch),6) = 'SELECT' THEN '(' + @DBFetch + ')' ELSE @DBFetch END
    SET @Bank = REPLACE(@Bank,         CHAR(94),CHAR(39))
    SET @Bank = REPLACE(@Bank,CHAR(45)+CHAR(45),CHAR(32))
    SET @Bank = REPLACE(@Bank,CHAR(47)+CHAR(42),CHAR(32))
END

IF @DBWhere IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @Cash = REPLACE(@DBWhere,'WHERE'       ,CHAR(32))
    SET @Cash = REPLACE(@Cash,         CHAR(94),CHAR(39))
    SET @Cash = REPLACE(@Cash,CHAR(45)+CHAR(45),CHAR(32))
    SET @Cash = REPLACE(@Cash,CHAR(47)+CHAR(42),CHAR(32))
END

IF @DBThere IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @Risk = REPLACE(@DBThere,'ORDER BY'    ,CHAR(32))
    SET @Risk = REPLACE(@Risk,         CHAR(94),CHAR(39))
    SET @Risk = REPLACE(@Risk,CHAR(45)+CHAR(45),CHAR(32))
    SET @Risk = REPLACE(@Risk,CHAR(47)+CHAR(42),CHAR(32))
END

SET @DBAI = ''
SET @DBAO = ''
SET @DBAU = ''

SET @Task = 'SELECT * INTO ' + @DBAE + ' FROM ' + @Bank + ' AS T WHERE 0 = 1'
IF @Status = 0 EXECUTE (@Task) SET @Return = @@ERROR
IF @Status = 0 SET @Status = @Return

-- For all columns (Fields) in the table.
DECLARE Fields CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT '['+C.name+']', C.colid, T.name, C.isnullable, C.iscomputed, C.length, C.prec, C.scale
FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects AS O
JOIN tempdb.dbo.syscolumns AS C
  ON O.id = C.id
JOIN tempdb.dbo.systypes AS T
  ON C.xusertype = T.xusertype
WHERE O.name = @DBAE
ORDER BY C.colid

SET @Retain = @@ERROR IF @Status = 0 SET @Status = @Retain

OPEN Fields

SET @Retain = @@ERROR IF @Status = 0 SET @Status = @Retain

FETCH NEXT FROM Fields INTO @Same, @Rank, @Kind, @Mask, @Bond, @Size, @Wide, @More

SET @Retain = @@ERROR IF @Status = 0 SET @Status = @Retain

-- Convert to character for header.
SET @HeaderString = ''
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @cDelimiter nvarchar(9)
DECLARE @cTextQuote nvarchar(9)
DECLARE @TypeFound bit
SET @sql = N'select @cDelimiter = ' + @Delimiter
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@cDelimiter varchar(9) output', @cDelimiter output
SET @sql = N'select @cTextQuote = ' + @TextQuote
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@cTextQuote varchar(9) output', @cTextQuote output

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 AND @Status = 0
BEGIN
    SET @TypeFound = 0

    -- Build header.
    IF LEN(@HeaderString) > 0 SET @HeaderString = @HeaderString + @cDelimiter + ISNULL(@cTextQuote + REPLACE(@Same, @cTextQuote, REPLICATE(@cTextQuote, 2))+@cTextQuote, SPACE(0))
    IF LEN(@HeaderString) = 0 SET @HeaderString = ISNULL(@cTextQuote + REPLACE(@Same, @cTextQuote, REPLICATE(@cTextQuote, 2))+@cTextQuote, SPACE(0))

    IF @Kind IN ('char','nchar','varchar','nvarchar','text','ntext','sysname','xml')
    BEGIN
        IF @NullQuoted = 0
        BEGIN
            IF @Rank = 1 SET @DBAU =                            ' ISNULL('+@TextQuote+'+REPLACE(' + @Same + ','+@TextQuote+',REPLICATE('+@TextQuote+',2))+'+@TextQuote+',SPACE(0))'
            IF @Rank > 1 SET @DBAU = @DBAU + '+' + @Delimiter + '+ISNULL('+@TextQuote+'+REPLACE(' + @Same + ','+@TextQuote+',REPLICATE('+@TextQuote+',2))+'+@TextQuote+',SPACE(0))'
        END
        IF @NullQuoted = 1
        BEGIN
            IF @Rank = 1 SET @DBAU =                            ' ISNULL('+@TextQuote+'+REPLACE(' + @Same + ','+@TextQuote+',REPLICATE('+@TextQuote+',2))+'+@TextQuote+','+@TextQuote+'+'+@TextQuote+')'
            IF @Rank > 1 SET @DBAU = @DBAU + '+' + @Delimiter + '+ISNULL('+@TextQuote+'+REPLACE(' + @Same + ','+@TextQuote+',REPLICATE('+@TextQuote+',2))+'+@TextQuote+','+@TextQuote+'+'+@TextQuote+')'
        END
        SET @TypeFound = 1
    END

    IF @Kind IN ('bit','tinyint','smallint','int','bigint')
    BEGIN
        IF @NullQuoted = 0
        BEGIN
            IF @Rank = 1 SET @DBAU =                            ' ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(128),' + @Same + '),SPACE(0))'
            IF @Rank > 1 SET @DBAU = @DBAU + '+' + @Delimiter + '+ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(128),' + @Same + '),SPACE(0))'
        END
        IF @NullQuoted = 1
        BEGIN
            IF @Rank = 1 SET @DBAU =                            ' ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(128),' + @Same + '),'+@TextQuote+'+'+@TextQuote+')'
            IF @Rank > 1 SET @DBAU = @DBAU + '+' + @Delimiter + '+ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(128),' + @Same + '),'+@TextQuote+'+'+@TextQuote+')'
        END
        SET @TypeFound = 1
    END

    IF @Kind IN ('numeric','decimal','money','smallmoney','float','real')
    BEGIN
        IF @NullQuoted = 0
        BEGIN
            IF @Rank = 1 SET @DBAU =                            ' ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(128),' + @Same + '),SPACE(0))'
            IF @Rank > 1 SET @DBAU = @DBAU + '+' + @Delimiter + '+ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(128),' + @Same + '),SPACE(0))'
        END
        IF @NullQuoted = 1
        BEGIN
            IF @Rank = 1 SET @DBAU =                            ' ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(128),' + @Same + '),'+@TextQuote+'+'+@TextQuote+')'
            IF @Rank > 1 SET @DBAU = @DBAU + '+' + @Delimiter + '+ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(128),' + @Same + '),'+@TextQuote+'+'+@TextQuote+')'
        END
        SET @TypeFound = 1
    END

    IF @Kind IN ('uniqueidentifier','geometry','geography')
    BEGIN
        IF @NullQuoted = 0
        BEGIN
            IF @Rank = 1 SET @DBAU =                            ' ISNULL('+@TextQuote+'+CONVERT(varchar(128),' + @Same + ')+'+@TextQuote+',SPACE(0))'
            IF @Rank > 1 SET @DBAU = @DBAU + '+' + @Delimiter + '+ISNULL('+@TextQuote+'+CONVERT(varchar(128),' + @Same + ')+'+@TextQuote+',SPACE(0))'
        END
        IF @NullQuoted = 1
        BEGIN
            IF @Rank = 1 SET @DBAU =                            ' ISNULL('+@TextQuote+'+CONVERT(varchar(128),' + @Same + ')+'+@TextQuote+','+@TextQuote+'+'+@TextQuote+')'
            IF @Rank > 1 SET @DBAU = @DBAU + '+' + @Delimiter + '+ISNULL('+@TextQuote+'+CONVERT(varchar(128),' + @Same + ')+'+@TextQuote+','+@TextQuote+'+'+@TextQuote+')'
        END
        SET @TypeFound = 1
    END

    IF @Kind IN ('datetime2','datetime','smalldatetime','time','date','datetimeoffset')
    BEGIN
        IF @NullQuoted = 0
        BEGIN
            IF @Rank = 1 SET @DBAU =                            ' ISNULL('+@TextQuote+'+CONVERT(varchar(128),' + @Same + ','+convert(varchar(3),@DateTimeStyle)+')+'+@TextQuote+',SPACE(0))'
            IF @Rank > 1 SET @DBAU = @DBAU + '+' + @Delimiter + '+ISNULL('+@TextQuote+'+CONVERT(varchar(128),' + @Same + ','+convert(varchar(3),@DateTimeStyle)+')+'+@TextQuote+',SPACE(0))'
        END
        IF @NullQuoted = 1
        BEGIN
            IF @Rank = 1 SET @DBAU =                            ' ISNULL('+@TextQuote+'+CONVERT(varchar(128),' + @Same + ','+convert(varchar(3),@DateTimeStyle)+')+'+@TextQuote+','+@TextQuote+'+'+@TextQuote+')'
            IF @Rank > 1 SET @DBAU = @DBAU + '+' + @Delimiter + '+ISNULL('+@TextQuote+'+CONVERT(varchar(128),' + @Same + ','+convert(varchar(3),@DateTimeStyle)+')+'+@TextQuote+','+@TextQuote+'+'+@TextQuote+')'
        END
        SET @TypeFound = 1
    END

    IF @TypeFound = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @Retain = 'ERROR: Data type ' + UPPER(@Kind) + ' was used but not supported by SaveDelimitedColumns.'
        SET @Status = @Retain
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM Fields INTO @Same, @Rank, @Kind, @Mask, @Bond, @Size, @Wide, @More

    SET @Retain = @@ERROR IF @Status = 0 SET @Status = @Retain
END

CLOSE Fields DEALLOCATE Fields

IF LEN(@DBAU) = 0 SET @DBAU = '*'

IF @PCWrite IS NOT NULL AND (@DBUltra = 0) AND (@Header = 1)
BEGIN
    SET @HeaderString = replace(@HeaderString, '"', '""')
    SET @DBAI = ' SELECT ' + CHAR(39) + @HeaderString + CHAR(39) + ' UNION ALL SELECT '
END
ELSE 
    SET @DBAI = ' SELECT '

SET @DBAO = ' FROM ' + @Bank + ' AS T'
    + CASE WHEN @DBWhere IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ' WHERE (' + @Cash + ') AND 0 = 0' END
    + CASE WHEN @DBThere IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ' ORDER BY ' + @Risk END

-- Output where @DBUltra = 0 (Uses XP_CMDSHELL \ BCP)
IF @PCWrite IS NOT NULL AND @DBUltra = 0
BEGIN
    SET @Wish = 'USE ' + DB_NAME() + @DBAI + @DBAU + @DBAO
    SET @Work = 'BCP "' + @Wish + '" QUERYOUT "' + @PCWrite + '" -w -T -S "' + @@SERVERNAME + '" '
    -- PRINT @Work
    EXECUTE @Return = master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @Work, NO_OUTPUT
    SET @Retain = @@ERROR
    IF @Status = 0 SET @Status = @Retain
    IF @Status = 0 SET @Status = @Return

    IF @Status <> 0 GOTO ABORT
END

-- Output where @DBUltra = 1 (Uses Ole Automation)
IF @PCWrite IS NOT NULL AND @DBUltra = 1
BEGIN
    IF @Status = 0 EXECUTE @Return = sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject', @Fuse OUTPUT
    SET @Retain = @@ERROR
    IF @Status = 0 SET @Status = @Retain
    IF @Status = 0 SET @Status = @Return

    IF @Status = 0 EXECUTE @Return = sp_OAMethod @Fuse, 'CreateTextFile', @File OUTPUT, @PCWrite, -1
    SET @Retain = @@ERROR
    IF @Status = 0 SET @Status = @Retain
    IF @Status = 0 SET @Status = @Return

    IF @Status <> 0 GOTO ABORT
END

SET @DBAI = 'DECLARE Records CURSOR GLOBAL FAST_FORWARD FOR' + @DBAI

IF @Status = 0 EXECUTE (@DBAI+@DBAU+@DBAO) SET @Return = @@ERROR
IF @Status = 0 SET @Status = @Return

OPEN Records
SET @Retain = @@ERROR IF @Status = 0 SET @Status = @Retain

FETCH NEXT FROM Records INTO @Next
SET @Retain = @@ERROR IF @Status = 0 SET @Status = @Retain

-- Header.
SET @HeaderDone = 0
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 AND @Status = 0
BEGIN
    IF @PCWrite IS NOT NULL AND @DBUltra = 1
    BEGIN
        -- Write header (FILE).
        IF (@Header = 1) and (@HeaderDone = 0)
        BEGIN
            SET @Save = @HeaderString + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
            IF @Status = 0 EXECUTE @Return = sp_OAMethod @File, 'Write', NULL, @Save
            SET @HeaderDone = 1
        END

        -- Write the data (FILE).
        SET @Save = @Next + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
        IF @Status = 0 EXECUTE @Return = sp_OAMethod @File, 'Write', NULL, @Save
        IF @Status = 0 SET @Status = @Return
    END

    IF @PCWrite IS NULL
    BEGIN
        -- Print header (TEXT).
        IF (@Header = 1) and (@HeaderDone = 0)
        BEGIN
            PRINT @HeaderString + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
            SET @HeaderDone = 1
        END
        PRINT @Next
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM Records INTO @Next
    SET @Retain = @@ERROR IF @Status = 0 SET @Status = @Retain
END

CLOSE Records DEALLOCATE Records

-- Close output file (Ole Automation)
IF @PCWrite IS NOT NULL AND @DBUltra = 1
BEGIN
    EXECUTE @Return = sp_OAMethod @File, 'Close', NULL
    IF @Status = 0 SET @Status = @Return

    EXECUTE @Return = sp_OADestroy @File
    IF @Status = 0 SET @Status = @Return

    EXECUTE @Return = sp_OADestroy @Fuse
    IF @Status = 0 SET @Status = @Return
END

ABORT: -- This label is referenced when OLE automation fails.

IF @Status = 1 OR @Status NOT BETWEEN 0 AND 50000 RAISERROR ('SaveDelimitedColumns Windows Error [%d]', 16, 1, @Status)

SET @Task = 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects WHERE name = ' + CHAR(39) + @DBAE + CHAR(39) + ') DROP TABLE ' + @DBAE
EXECUTE (@Task);

RETURN (@Status);

END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the lines

```
SET @HeaderString = replace(@HeaderString, '[', '')
SET @HeaderString = replace(@HeaderString, ']', '')
```

right after the line

```
CLOSE Fields DEALLOCATE Fields
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT '['+C.name+']', C.colid, T.name, C.isnullable, C.iscomputed, C.length, C.prec, C.scale
```

Right there you added the [ ] to your column names, C.Name is the column name. Most times you can get away with not using the braces, unless your tables use reserved words for column names.

```
SELECT C.name, C.colid, T.name, C.isnullable, C.iscomputed, C.length, C.prec, C.scale
```

Alternatively you could trim them at the end, right after you CLOSE and DEALOCATE your Fields cursor, like this:

```
CLOSE Fields DEALLOCATE Fields
SET @HeaderString = replace(replace(@HeaderString, ']', ''), '[', '')
```

Comment: Solution 1 is not good. It uses the string also to query the columns of the table. If the square brackets are missing, then there might be problems with column names that need to be escaped.

Comment: @nharrer As said in the answer - " Most times you can get away with not using the braces, unless your tables use reserved words for column names."

Comment: True, I rarely use the brackets myself when I know the tables I am working with. But in utility code like this which could come across all kinds of tables it's good practice to add the brackets. You second solution is good, since that is only used for generating the header row.